# Append a JS to body element

Tags: javascript, append, appendto

why does message box not appear? Many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('<script>alert("hi");</' + 'script>').appendTo(document.body);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span>my test</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?  Scripts would normally be appended to the head element, not the body element to accomplish dynamic loading and usually you create a script element and specify a `.src` URL and then append that to the head element.

Comment: Scripts can be in either the head or body, I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: ok, I have a problem with a CMS which adds and "addthis.com" javascript to a page with wrong settings. This script lives within the body element and I need to append another script to the end of the body element which would change one of script properties. The solution is explained here: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/352733-how-to-remove-hash-from-url-, and unfortunately it doesn't work when I use $(document).ready() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must wrap in in a `$(document).ready`.

Otherwise it won't be able to find `body` because it hasn't loaded yet.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<script>alert("hi");</' + 'script>').appendTo(document.body);
})
```

Comment: thank you. I mark it as a solution, although my problem is still not solved. Could you please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283707/addthis-ads-a-hashtag-and-id-to-url-how-to-remove-it